# Self Defining Classes in Ruby?

Tags: ruby

I'm trying to understand exactly what the piece of code below accomplishes and how it works.

```
class Nodes < Struct.new(:nodes) #Create a struct with array hash nodes
    def <<(node)
        nodes << node
        self
    end
end
```

Comment: I cannot get that to work, are you sure it is correct? I would expect `class Nodes < Struct.new(:nodes); def << node ...` instead, with changes to number of `<` in first line and some added whitespace in second line.

Comment: You're right. I made a mistake when copying it over.

Comment: should be `def << node` or `def <<(node)`

Comment: What makes you think there is metaprogramming going on here?

Comment: This: `class Nodes < Struct.new(:nodes)`. If it is not metaprogramming, I'll remove the tag.

Comment: @theideasmith: no, it's not. It's completely ordinary ruby (although using parts of stdlib you probably haven't seen before). I went ahead and removed the tags for you :)

Answer (score 4):

`Struct.new(:nodes)` creates a new anonymous [`Struct`](http://ruby-doc.org//core-2.2.0/Struct.html) subclass with a single member `:nodes`. According to the docs you would usually assign it to a constant, e.g.:

```
Foo = Struct.new(:nodes)
foo = Foo.new([1, 2, 3]) #=> #<struct Foo nodes=[1, 2, 3]>
foo.nodes                #=> [1, 2, 3]
```

#### Subclassing `Struct.new`

`class Nodes < Struct.new(...)` creates a new class `Nodes` with the anonymous `Struct` subclass as its superclass:

```
Nodes.ancestors
#=> [Nodes, #<Class:0x007fa0320032d0>, Struct, Enumerable, Object, Kernel, BasicObject]
#                       ^
#                       |
#            anonymous Struct sublass
```

This allows you to call `super` when overriding methods from the `Struct` subclass, e.g.:

```
class Nodes < Struct.new(:nodes)
  def nodes
    super
  end
end
```

Comment: Should be `< Struct` not `<<`. Probably got carried away because of the other `<<` operators.